# Call function by default?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
var foo;
foo.bar = function { };
foo.variable1 = "Hello World";
foo.variable2 = 5;
```

... and somehow make it so that I can:

```
function example() {
    foo(); // <-- have this call foo.bar()
    foo.variable1 = "Goodbye World"; // <-- but still have this work 
    }
```

Comment: Even though this is possible I wouldn't recommend it.
Use the object notation (JSON) for objects and function for functions...

Something being possible in a language doesn't mean it's good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. Functions are just objects, too.

```
var foo = function () { alert("Hi!") };
foo.variable1 = "Hello world";

console.log(foo.variable1);
foo();
```

Comment: To compare your answer against Brighams, if I decided to change foo() to a different function later in the code, would `foo = function() { /*new function */}` keep foo.variable1 intact?

Comment: variable1 would then "go away." It's a property on the function object itself, so if you assign a different function object to the variable, you'll lose the properties on the first one. As mentioned elsewhere, it's probably better to rethink the structure of your code and avoid assigning properties to functions.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than you think.

```
var foo = function() {
  foo.bar();
};

foo.bar = function() {
  console.log('Hello World. '+ foo.variable1);
};

foo.variable1 = "Goodbye World";

foo(); // "Hello World. Goodbye World"
```

Comment: In this case, if you reassign `foo` to another variable (`fum`), then reassign something else to `foo`, calling `fum()` will try to call `bar` on the new value of `foo` instead of on itself, which is why I prefer using `this` in this case.

Comment: This doesn't work (at least in the test I just did) because you reference `foo.bar()` before it is declared and it cannot be declared first since assigning `foo` to a function would clear `foo.bar()`

Comment: You sure about that, @FatalKeystroke? http://jsfiddle.net/V95Nf/ Edit: Oh, I see, you mean that it doesn't work to assign that function to foo and then assign *another* function to foo later on. Yes, that doesn't work, for the reason I described in the comment on my answer. For what it's worth, though, it's perfectly fine to reference a variable or property "before it's declared" (did you mean before it's assigned?) as long as it exists once the code referencing it is actually executed.

Comment: Apologies, I tested Brighams answer (which he seems to have deleted) and responded to Alex Wayne by mistake. For reference to future readers, Brighams answer was the same as this, but called `this.bar()` rather than `foo.bar()`

Comment: I am curious though, why would `foo.bar()` succeed and `this.bar()` fail if the order of assignment doesn't matter?

Comment: `this` is tricky in JavaScript. In short a function run like `someFunc()` will have `this === window` (in a browser). But `obj.method()` with have `this === obj`. It's about how the method is invoked. There are ways to override that, however. But function context is a much more complicated issue that doesn't belong in this comment thread.